# Some kind of bill calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tryed to create a calculator what calculate a bill with a tip, when it splited
in the input entered pepole.
I getted an idea on the DigitalOcean: 
[a link] (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/built-in-python-3-functions-for-working-with-numbers)
I tryed to change it little bit more excited, but im pretty rookie and cant understand what i will do wrong.
At start i just declared a variables what i will use. That know at myself.
How to say im trying to make a calculator, what useing 3 input areas: 1st i will enter a bill, lets say example 125.50 eur, 2nd i will enter a tip example 15%, it should be 0,15, then i calculate the total bill, next i will enter how many persons pay a bill, example: 4 and calculate, how much everyone must pay depended a numbers i enter, and at last print the answer on the screen, with 2 floating points after comma. NB: dont know how to describe it more clearly.
Sorry for type errors, that is my first post.

## Variables for useing on code

```
    bill = 0  

    tip = 0 

    split = 0

    total = 0   

    eachPay = 0
```

## Code

```
    strbill = input("Enter a bill: \n")

    strtip = input("Enter a tip: \n")

    total = bill + (bill * tip)

    strsplit = input("Enter at how many persons split a bill: \n"

    print("Every person must pay %.2f" % eachPay)
```

Program working fine, i can give the values on the inouts and all, but the progam gives me answer that every people should pay 0.00EUR, no matter what i will wrote on the inputs.

Comment: Please note that your comments behind hashes are showing up as headers in this post. Try and edit it so that it is correctly shown. Also, comments not written in English do not add to the post. It's better if you eliminate them. Please include details of what's the output you obtain, and what would be your desired output.

Comment: Can you convert `bill = 0` to `bill = 0.` (note the `.`), and then the same for `tip, split, total, eachPay` as well. If your logic is correct, this will work.

Comment: It's possible Python is treating all your variables as integers, so try casting your variables to float.

Comment: Are you missing some code here? You never use the `str...` variables, you never set `bill`, `tip` or `split` to anything other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use float variables. Cast read inputs to floats or integers.
Remember that using floats like this for monetary calculations might result in rounding errors.

```
bill = 0.0
tip = 0.0
total = 0.0
eachPay = 0.0
split = 0

bill = float(input("Enter a bill: \n"))
tip = float(input("Enter a tip: \n"))
split = int(input("Enter at how many persons split a bill: \n"))

total = bill + (bill * tip)
eachPay = total / split

print("Every person must pay %.2f" % eachPay)
```

Comment: How will using float variables make a difference, given that `/` in Python 3 always performs "true" division?